# Laravel + Minio s3 = AWS HTTP error: cURL error 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, minio

recently I updated my PHP to PHP 8.2.6. It was 8.0

Now I was testing Minio on my Laravel APP, when I tried to get a s3 object I'm getting this error:

> Error executing "ListObjectsV2" on
> "http://localhost:9000/datalake?list-type=2&prefix=1%2Ffiles%2FKKu17oUjsxi3EmGrQMhnJzS38rwiFpE7GgrXxSoq.txt%2F&max-keys=1";
> AWS HTTP error: cURL error 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
> (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I read that it can be related to Docker, but I can't find a solution.